# Load more JSON data using Endless/sth else?

Tags: android, json, listview, lazy-loading

I have a restaurant finder app that retrieves data from a JSON file.

Right now I have around 313 restaurants and by I have successfully made them viewable in my custom listview. Now my problem is since thats a lot of data and more will be added soon, I wanted to implement a load more data on scroll as it already takes a few sec to load.

This is my JSON file:http://www.petuuk.com/android/allRestaurantList2.php

I have this "SearchAll" class, where all the code for loading takes place, the user comes in after clicking Search All button in my Mainactivity.

If anyone could kindly and specifically show **WHERE and WHAT** code to put in to successfully implement a **LOAD MORE SCROLL ON SCROLL**, that would really help.

I am newbie, so just giving links wouldn't really out that much. May be you can help me implement endless adapter which should be perfect for my sort of thing?

```
public class SearchAll extends ListActivity {

ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//make json parser Object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restaurant_list;

//Restaurant Json array
JSONArray restaurants = null;

private static final 
String URL_RESTAURANT_LIST = "http://www.petuuk.com/android/allRestaurantList2.php";

//all JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_ID = "login_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
private static final String TAG_RATING = "rating";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_all);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    //Check for Internet Connection
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        //Internet connection not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(SearchAll.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please Check Your Internet Connection", false);
        //stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    restaurant_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadRestaurants().execute();

   //get ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RestaurantProfile.class);
            String loginId = ((TextView) view.
                    findViewById(R.id.login_id)).
                    getText().toString();

            String res_name = ((TextView) view.
                    findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name)).
                    getText().toString();


            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, loginId);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_NAME, res_name);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });


}


class LoadRestaurants extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    //Show Progress Dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchAll.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading All Restaurants...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        //building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //Getting JSON from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_RESTAURANT_LIST, "GET", params);

        //Log Cat Response Check
        Log.d("Areas JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {
            restaurants = new JSONArray(json);

            if (restaurants != null) {
                //loop through all restaurants
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Storing each json  object in the variable.
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);

                    //Creating New Hashmap
                    HashMap<String, String>  map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //adding each child node to Hashmap key
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                    map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);

                    //adding HashList to ArrayList
                    restaurant_list.add(map);
                }

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        //dismiss the dialog
        pDialog.dismiss();


        //Updating UI from the Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SearchAll.this, restaurant_list,
                        R.layout.listview_restaurants, new String[]{
                        TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_LOCATION, TAG_RATING}, new int[]{
                        R.id.login_id, R.id.restaurant_name,
                        R.id.address, R.id.rating});

                setListAdapter(adapter);


            }
       });

    }
}}
```

I am also adding my layout files, though they are not needed but just in case some one is having a problem making a custom listview, this might help them out.

**Layout file 1: activity_search_all.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#bbb"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    ></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout file 2: listview_restaurants.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"

    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/restaurant_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/restaurant_name"
    android:background="#ffb400"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/restaurant_name"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_below="@+id/restaurant_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/area_id"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/area_id" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE:1.1 
So by suggestion of @Alok, i have added a new "EndlessScrollListener" class, copied and pasted. Then on my onCreate method of my "SearchAll" class as given above, this is what I have coded, I know i need to put something in **OnloadMore** method but what? I'm a newbie please help me out by coding and commenting your code.

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your request to server fetches  all data at time it is better to fetch certain number of data in one request so that when user scrolls down to bottom of loaded ListView you can make another request to fetch more data inside this method  recursively
 ListView yourListViw=(ListView)infl.findViewById(R.id.yourListId);

```
        yourListViw.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

           // check if it is the last item of your list and load more items
                 int currentPosition = yourListViw.getFirstVisiblePosition();
           // call similar async task to load more data with newly added json data
           // set the position of list to latest item 
                yourListViw.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

                }     

             });
```

Comment: can you kindly elaborate the code, i have stated above i cant simply code complex methods like these. Kindly have a look at my code and help me out please!

Comment: inside this method:you need to call another async task either by reusing your earlier class or creating another similar class to load more elements on your list adapter

Comment: first tell me where is your more data coming from? will you request to same url for more data ?

Comment: Yes, at this time, when I launch "SearchAll", all the data loads and it takes some time. So as soon as more data gets inserted in the database, it will take more time to load the JSON file. So please see the code and help me do the onScroll load. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A common application feature is to have an AdapterView (such as a ListView or GridView) that automatically loads more items as the user scrolls through the items (aka infinite scroll). This is done by triggering a request for more data once the user crosses a threshold of remaining items before they've hit the end.

Every AdapterView has support for binding to the OnScrollListener events which are triggered whenever a user scrolls through the collection. Using this system, we can define a basic EndlessScrollListener which supports most use cases by creating our own class that extends OnScrollListener:

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;

public EndlessScrollListener() {
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
    this.currentPage = startPage;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) 
    {
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
    }

    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        currentPage++;
    }

    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // Don't take any action on changed
}
}
```

Notice that this is an abstract class, and that in order to use this, you must extend this base class and define the onLoadMore method to actually retrieve the new data. We can define now an anonymous class within any activity that extends EndlessScrollListener and bind that to the AdapterView. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ... the usual 
    ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    // Attach the listener to the AdapterView onCreate
    lvItems.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
            // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to your AdapterView
        customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page); 
            // or customLoadMoreDataFromApi(totalItemsCount); 
    }
    });
}

// Append more data into the adapter
public void customLoadMoreDataFromApi(int offset) {
  // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
  // Use the offset value and add it as a parameter to your API request to retrieve paginated data.
  // Deserialize API response and then construct new objects to append to the adapter
}
}
```

Now as you scroll, items will be automatically filling in because the onLoadMore method will be triggered once the user crosses the visibleThreshold. This approach works equally well for a GridView and the listener gives access to both the page as well as the totalItemsCount to support both pagination and offset based fetching.

If you are running into problems, please carefully consider the following suggestions:

Make sure to setup the setOnScrollListener listener in the onCreate method of the Activity and not later on otherwise you may encounter unexpected issues.

In order for the pagination system to continue working reliably, you should make sure to clear the adapter of items (or notify adapter after clearing the array) before appending new items to the list.

In order for this pagination system to trigger, keep in mind that as customLoadMoreDataFromApi is called, new data needs to be appended to the existing data source. In other words, only clear items from the list when on the initial "page". Subsequent "pages" of data should be appended to the existing data.

Comment: please see my updated code, I have a UPDATE para at the bottom. I dont know what exactly to code in LoadMore. Please help me out if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the number of jsonObjects that API throws, the best solution would be introduce a page number request in the API itself. Then, you could listen to the last scrolled position and show a load more button there, and when the user clicks on that button, you could ask for more data with the server and manage accordingly. I could help you with the paging handling on the android side but you got to have a proper server setup first. Good luck :)

Comment: do u need my JSON code then, the php file I shared i meant. THen can you make the query like that?

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED ANSWER:DOWN VOTE DUE TO SUGGESTION TO PUT LIST VIEW INSIDE SCROLL VIEW[WHICH HAS BEEN REMOVED]**

```
ListView yourListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListId);


        yourListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                }     

             });
```

Comment: Putting a listview inside a scrollview is a bad design and should be avoided at all cost (and yes, the official documentation said so), considering header and footer for android listview for better performance